# ASP.Net MVC page with a section that contains partial view being submitted as part of the form post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a view that contains a partial view that is brought into a `@section` on the layout page.

How can I include the fields in that partial view in a section in the form collection on submission?

If I put it into the `using(Html.BeginForm()){@section }` the section does not get placed in the proper place on the form. If I don't include it in the using section the fields don't get submitted as part of the form collection.

Any way to make this work?

```
@using(Html.Beginform("MyMethod","home", FormMethod.Post)){
@Html.Partial(MyModel)
<input type="submit" value="continue"/>
}
@section LowerLeftBlock{
@HtmlPartial("partials/_additionalformfields")
}
```

And the layout page:

```
<div id="body">
@RenderSection("LeftBlock",false)
@RenderBody()
</div>
```

Comment: Any code samples to help with?

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to do.  Sections are used to allow a content page to render content in a layout page.  You would not place a section within a form, unless that form were in the layout, which doesn't seem to be the case here.  Why are you trying to put your section inside your form?  Are you trying to render part of your from as a side navigation bar?  and part in the main page?

Comment: The section contains several fields that I would like to have rendered as part of the form so that I can access them in the formcollection when the form is posted. The reason they are in sections is for layout purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to copy the additional fields into the form, either when the page is fully loaded or just before the form is submitted. Something like this might do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#theform').submit(function(){
          $("#lowerleftblock input").appendTo("#destinationform");
      });
  });
</script>
```

You would obviously need to adjust the css selectors in the sample code above for this to work.

You may want to

- See [the jQuery docs for more info on appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo).
- See [the jQuery docs for more info on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).